# Is there an auto-run key?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I'm getting pretty tired of holding down control and <kbd>W</kbd> at the same time to make my character sprint. Is there a way to auto-run?

Comment: Good question for which there are 5 people who found the answer relevant and useful. Upvote the question too!

Comment: the `W` key can be held down by an [AutoHotkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) script instead of my finger though - https://github.com/Aprillion/banished_utils/blob/master/toggle_w.ahk

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change the run key from the default "press and hold" to a "push once to toggle" option. For whatever reason, in the time between the demo and the full game, the default was changed from the latter to the former (Needless to say, it was the first thing I changed back).

[image]

There doesn't seem to be an "always run" button, so do bear in mind you'll have to re-toggle the run button every time you come to a full stop, or take damage, etc.

Still loads better than holding the button down all the time!

Comment: Would you mind explaining how to change it back to toggle? It might be helpful for people (like me) who don't usually change the defaults :p

Comment: @spugsley Look at my answer, now look at me. Now back at my answer. Bam! Now my answer has a picture explanation. ;)

Comment: This is sprint toggle, not autorun.. It allows you to sprint with a single click on ctrl instead of pressing it all the time. But you still have to press the movement key constantly.